# How to expand a mapping into inputs for a terraform resource/module?

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Consider the following module example (namely `mymodule`, which is declared in some git repo):

```
# vars.tf
variable "input_1" {type=string, default="foo"}
variable "input_2" {type=list(string), default=["bar"]}
```

```
# main.tf
resource "cloud_some_resource" "example" {
  input_1 = var.input_1
  input_2 = var.input_2
}
```

Now this module is used in a codebase like so:

```
# some_resource.tf
module "mymodule" {
  source = "git::git/mymodule.git"
  input_1 = "value"
  input_2 = ["other"]
}
```

This all works fine, however, `cloud_some_resource` has several other inputs I can use, like `input_3`, `input_4` and so on. But since only inputs 1 and 2 are declared in the module, I can only pass them to `cloud_some_resource`. Sure I can contribute to `mymodule` and set the other inputs in `vars.tf` and `main.tf`, although that is cumbersome (will require a PR) and not very DRY, IMHO.

My question is: can we declare a flexible mapping and expand that as input to `main.tf`? Something like python's `**kwargs`, e.g.:

```
# vars.tf
variable "config" {type=map(object)}
```

```
# main.tf
resource "cloud_some_resource" "example" {
  expand(
    merge(
      {
        input_1="foo"
        input_2=["bar"]
      },
      var.config
    )
  )
}
```

And then use this in `some_resource.tf`:

```
# some_resource.tf
module "mymodule" {
  source = "git::git/mymodule.git"
  config = {
    input_1 = "value"
    input_2 = ["other"]
  }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is no. Even if you could pass it like that to the module, at the end of the day it has to be declared in the resource literally. However, some resources from providers support a function called `dynamic` which can declare parameters dynamically but this will need a major code change in the module to work anyway. [dynamic-blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks)

Comment: You may want to manage the resources directly and avoid declaring the module if it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: @Prav, that short answer was what I feared... Regarding the `dynamic` blocks, as far as I could understand, they don't really provide the functionality I am asking for. If you feel differently, please post an answer with your solution/workaround, I will gladly accept it!

Comment: @MattSchuchard, although I appreciate the alternative, of course this is a proof-of-concept. In the real case scenario, the module defines several resources, it would not be wise to take a step back...

Comment: There is no way that you can pass any input in the `module interface` without defining them in the `root module ` itself(resources). Those inputs have to exist beforehand, you can set their default values on the root module level, and can override them whenever needed or leave them unused to use the default values. That is why it is a best practice to parametrize all possible inputs/arguments of the resource in the module and set the default value `null` for optional inputs/arguments to let terraform-cloud-API decide the default values.